# Import modules that are above project root

Tags: python, django

I'm playing around with the following structure:

http://timmyomahony.com/blog/2012/11/09/general-django-project-structure-or-folder-layout/

Suppose I have some generic functions in the lib directory

```
foo.com     < -- site root
    lib/
    django_root/     < -- project root (checked into Github)
```

An import such as:

```
from ... lib import my_lib
```

Is giving me

```
ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package
```

Comment: Add `lib` path to your `PYTHONPATH`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two clean solutions.

1. For this to work, your lib has to be [Distutils](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html) compatible (have a `setup.py`) file. If it does, then you can simply install it with `pip` with the [`e-`](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/usage.html#options) flag. Just do:

   ```
   pip install -e /full/path/to/foo.com/lib/
   ```

   That will install the library in editable mode, meaning that the lib will not be installed to `site-packages` but will create an egg symlink there. That means that any changes you will make to the files within the lib will automatically go live within your environment.
2. I don't think this is as nearly as clean as the first suggestion by this will work. Just add the lib to the PATH in your Django's `manage.py`:

   ```
   import os, sys
   root_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(__file__, '..', '..'))
   lib_path = os.path.join(root_path, 'lib')
   sys.path.insert(0, lib_path)
   # ...
   ```